# Spring JPA/Hibernate repository findOne method returns null

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm new to Spring and JPA/Hibernate and I pluck off my hair.

I'm making a CRUD application. I have an Entity "User", a Repository "UserRepository" and a Controller called "UserController". Moreover I'm using MySQL.

I've succeeded in creating `User`s (they are saved in the MySQL database) when I execute a POST request. Unfortunately when I try to retrieve a User with the `findOne()` method of my `UserRepository`, I get `null` back. My DELETE requests also fail.

I'm on this issue for few days now.

This is my `User` Entity :

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    private String nomUtilisateur;

    @NotNull
    private Date dateInscription;

    @NotNull
    private long nbSoireeOrganisee;

    @NotNull
    private float noteGenerale;

    public User(String aEmail, String aNomUtilisateur) {
        email = aEmail;
        nomUtilisateur = aNomUtilisateur;
        dateInscription = new Date();
        nbSoireeOrganisee = 0;
        noteGenerale = 0;


    }

    public User() {
        // Only JPA
    }

    public String getUserEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return nomUtilisateur;
    }

    public Date getDateInscription() {
        return dateInscription;
    }

    public long getNbSoireeOrganisee() {
        return nbSoireeOrganisee;
    }

    public float getNoteGenerale() {
        return noteGenerale;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("User[name='%s']", this.nomUtilisateur);
    }
}
```

That's my `UserRepository`:

```
import fr.afti.proto.fact.models.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

@Transactional
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String> {

    User findByNomUtilisateur(String nomUtilisateur);
}
```

And this is my `UserController`:

```
import fr.afti.proto.fact.models.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    // CREATE User
    // This function works
    @PostMapping("/create/{aEmail}/{aNomUtilisateur}")
    public String create(@PathVariable String aEmail, @PathVariable String aNomUtilisateur) {
        try {
            User newUser = new User(aEmail, aNomUtilisateur);
            userRepository.saveAndFlush(newUser);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return "Error when trying to create a user";
        }
        return "User successfully created";
    }


    // DELETE User
    // This function doesn't work
    @DeleteMapping("/delete/user/{email}")
    public String delete(@PathVariable String email) {
        userRepository.delete(email);
        return "true";
    }

    // READ User
    // This funcction doesn't work
    @GetMapping("user/{email}")
    public
    @ResponseBody
    String getUserByMail(@PathVariable String email) {
        User uRes = userRepository.findOne(email); // THIS RETURN NULL
        //User uRes = userRepository.findByNomUtilisateur("Toto");
        return uRes.getUserName();
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: please post also findByNomUtilisateur impl

Comment: it's automatic it will be translate by JPA with a query like that : "SELECT * FROM user WHERE nomUtilisateur = ?(parameter)"

Comment: can you post the `findOne()` method?

Comment: He means this https://spring.io/blog/2011/02/10/getting-started-with-spring-data-jpa/

Comment: yes @xiumeteo understand what I wanted to say. Sorry I'm french...

Comment: Could you please provide the testcase? What is the return value of the `userRepository.saveAndFlush(newUser)` call?

Comment: @DominikSandjaja If by "testcase" you speak of unit test, I never made unit test of my life(I have to learn). But this call work because when I do a POST request a user entry is added in my database.

Comment: Just some ideas for debugging this: see if using a known literal string for the email works, see if findAll works (and brings all users).

Comment: @FredyTreboux yes it works when I put directly in my code a email it works. The findAll methods also works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a few small issues:

#### 1. Add the `email` property

In order to query an entity using its properties, it at least needs getters for those properties. So add the `email` property:

```
...
public String getUserEmail() {
    return email;
}
...
```

#### 2. Fix your `GET` and `DELETE` request mappings

If you send a `GET` request to your current controller:

```
GET localhost:8080/user/test@example.com
```

Spring considers everything after the last `.` character as a file extension, so `.com` will be truncated and `{email}` will be set to `test@example`.

That's why your `getUserByMail` method returns `null`.

You have a couple of options here:

#### 2.1 Either set the regular expression pattern for the email path variable:

```
@DeleteMapping("/delete/user/{email:.+}")
...

@GetMapping("user/{email:.+}")
...
```

#### 2.1 Or use a request parameter instead of a path variable

For example:

```
@GetMapping("user")
public String getUserByMail2(@RequestParam("email") String email) {
    User uRes = userRepository.findOne(email); // THIS RETURN NULL
    return uRes.getUserName();
}
```

and call it using:

```
GET localhost:8080/user?email=test%40example.com
```

See [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/behrangsa-public/stackoverflow/question42308442.zip) for a complete working example.

Comment: Thanks !!! But it strange like I said in comment to @Oleksandr Shpota when I removed the "@" from the email it works (even a "." is in the email). After when I try your solution it works ^^

Comment: You are welcome! In general, `@` should be URL encoded. So rather than `localhost:8080/user/test@example.com`, you should use `localhost:8080/user/test%40example.com`.